# Error: Replacement has length zero R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl, webscarab

I 'm trying to scrape http://then.gasbuddy.com/.

I'm running the next code in R

```
 library(RCurl)
 library(XML)
 doc <- htmlTreeParse('http://www.southcarolinagasprices.com/GasPriceSearch.aspx?typ=adv&fuel=A&srch=0&area=All%20Areas&station=All%20Stations&tme_limit=4')
rootNode <- xmlRoot(doc)

((rootNode[[2]][4])[1][[1]])[[15]][[1]][[11]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[8]][[1]][[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]

#<div class="p1"/>

x <- matrix(, nrow = 20, ncol = 4)

x[1,1] <- xmlValue(((rootNode[[2]][4])[1][[1]])[[15]][[1]][[11]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[8]][[1]][[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]])
```

But I have this error

> replacement has length zero

How can I subtract p1 and put it in a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've come up with an interesting way to get around their price obfuscation. Since they didn't restrict scraping in their Terms of Service, here's one way you can scrape the prices:

```
library(xml2)

doc <- read_html('http://www.southcarolinagasprices.com/GasPriceSearch.aspx?typ=adv&fuel=A&srch=0&area=All%20Areas&station=All%20Stations&tme_limit=4')

prices <- xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//div[@class='sp_p']")

sapply(prices, function(x) {
  as.numeric(paste(gsub("d", "\\.", 
                        gsub("^p", "", 
                             unlist(xml_attrs(xml_find_all(x, "./div"))))),
                   collapse=""))
})

##   [1] 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.67 1.68 1.69 1.69 1.69 1.69 1.69 1.69 1.69 1.69
##  [20] 1.70 1.71 1.72 1.72 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.74 1.74 1.74 1.74 1.74 1.74
##  [39] 1.74 1.74 1.74 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.76 1.76
##  [58] 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77
##  [77] 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77
##  [96] 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78
## [115] 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78
## [134] 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79
## [153] 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79
## [172] 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79
## [191] 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79
```

Comment: It works thank you, I am kinda new in R, do you know a way to convert this values to a data.frame?

Comment: can you expand on that a bit more? do you just want the gas prices or the entire "table" as a data frame? if it's the latter, it's prbly good for a new question vs expand the scope of this one

Comment: I just need this gas prices in a data.frame to export it to .csv or .txt

Comment: No, you can just use `writeLines`

Answer (score 1):

The error means what it says. Look at the return value from

```
xmlValue(((rootNode[[2]][4])[1][[1]])[[15]][[1]][[11]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[8]][[1]][[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]])
```

It's

```
character(0)
```

Because `<div class="p1"/>` is a self-closing tag that doesn't contain any text. As the error message indicates, it's an error in R to replace part of a vector with something that has length zero. If you want these length-zero results to return something like `NA` or `""`, you need to use an `if`/`else` construction.